# Add new element above other elements coming from API

Tags: angular

I have two components `add-product.component` and `show-list.component`

In my show-list component I have my list coming from list-product API, this API have 3 parameters in body (user_id, session_key, page). The 3rd parameter page is just for having the list-product divided into 15 when the page=0 and if the page=1 I got 30 elements ... etc

The problem is when I want to add product in `add-product.component` and at the same way I want the `show-list.component` display it without refreshing the page to get the API call again, So I want to add then new product in special way, and when the user refresh the page, the real element in API come and display in show-list Component.

I tried to call 2 API's to achieve this, so when I add new product the add-product API call and onSuccess the list-product API call, but the problem here is the element cannot be at first because I'm using push data like this:

```
this.result.data.products.forEach(item => {
this.data.push(item);
});
```

And in my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" id="{{item.product_id}}">

//product details

</div>
```

In my console:
[Elements from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfu0d.png)

Now if I add new product with id=3906 for example, how can I add this element above the others, I have no problem if the user refresh the page because it will be the first element already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your array of values sorted, one possible thing you can do is simply reorder your array after adding the new element(s) :

```
this.data.push(item); // or push many items 

this.data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.product_id - b.product_id;
});
```

This way the new value will be at its correct position.

Comment: @RoulaHalabi could you create a minimal working example using Plunker or StackBlitz ?

Comment: I'm not good at Plunker or StackBiltz and my code is complicated but kindly check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jm3x8i

Comment: any ideas please?

Comment: @RoulaHalabi What am I supposed to look at ? I only see the default start template, nothing that you added yourself to the StackBlitz,

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead of `Array.push()`, when you want to add element at beginning of array.

Comment: I was thinking of add this Element in DOM and then when the user refresh I will remove it because it will be already exist in API.